# Compare returns incorrect result in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

While comparing the columns of "ibeaconUuid" & "rawData", the non-zero column should return as "payload" column.

```
ip_dict = {'ibeaconUuid': ['0', 'E245F67', '0', '0'],
           'rawData': ['5F67E24',0,'5F67E24',0],
           'mac': ['A', 'B', 'C' , 'D']} 
ip_df = pd.DataFrame(ip_dict)
ip_df['payload_data'] = ip_df.apply(lambda x : x['ibeaconUuid'] if 
                        x['ibeaconUuid'] != 0  else x['rawData'] if 
                        x['rawData'] != 0 else 0, axis=1)
```

and the above expression returns as,

```
    ibeaconUuid  rawData mac payload_data
  0           0  5F67E24   A            0
  1     E245F67        0   B      E245F67
  2           0  5F67E24   C            0
  3           0        0   D            0
```

whereas my required result is,

```
    ibeaconUuid  rawData mac payload_data
  0           0  5F67E24   A      5F67E24      
  1     E245F67        0   B      E245F67
  2           0  5F67E24   C      5F67E24
  3           0        0   D            0
```

Comment: ip_df.apply(lambda x : x['ibeaconUuid'] if 
                        x['ibeaconUuid'] != '0'  else x['rawData'] if 
                        x['rawData'] != '0' else 0, axis=1)

Comment: @iamklaus, Thank you. I got it. Its because of the zero values are string in data frame.